# Calling loadView method to reload the uiview

Tags: ios, viewcontroller, superview

I have a case where all my subviews of a viewcontroller (say A) are declared in the loadView method. When I remove the viewcontroller's view (say B) from the superview and add back viewcontroller A's view to the superview, how can I reload the view? Subview B is on top of subview A and when I remove B I should be looking at an Update subview A.

Answer (score 0):

Simply removing the view doesn't destroy it. But if you have destroyed the view (by calling `[viewcontroller setView:nil]`), then simply calling `[viewcontroller view]` will reload the view. You should never call `loadView` - the system will do it for you.